# Is it safe to RaiseException(...) a win32 seh exception in a callback? (On both x86 and x64)

Tags: c, winapi, x86, x86-64, seh

In certain circumstances, I would like to call [`RaiseException()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms680552(v=vs.85).aspx) to raise an exception within a callback passed to a Win32 function.

As one example, I would like to call `RaiseException()` in an [`LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) and handle it in a `__try { } __except() { }` block much further down the call stack.

Is this "safe", in the sense that it will have predictable results on x86 and amd64? Is it "safe" in the sense that it will not leak resources†?

†: *Assume that any intermediate stack frames I control are set up in a manner that will not leak resources. I'm only concerned with Win32 API stack frames that are "opaque" to me.*

Comment: It is *supposed* to be safe, real programs throw SEH exceptions without any help.  STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION most commonly.  But there's trouble for a 32-bit program that runs in the Wow64 emulator for *certain* kind of messages.  You'll have to thoroughly test this.  Check the Remarks section of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: [When you transfer control across stack frames, all the frames in between need to be in on the joke](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/10/10347674.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is not safe to arbitrarily raise SEH exceptions when you are relying on being the first (and only) exception handler. There are a number of mechanisms that could intercept your exception first - anything acting as a debugger, for example - and take action which you do not expect.

This seems like a code smell - is there no other way to structure your code to avoid this? Could you just use a (less evil) goto?